# How to disconnect a Channel manually from listener in spring-rabbitmq + spring cloud

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have created a RabbitMQ application using Spring Cloud + Spring Boot and based on the following logic: I am closing the channel which will stop the assigned listener from accepting requests.

When I close the channel using `channel.close()` method, I am able to see the channel getting auto-created and calling the listener again.

Is there any way to disable the auto-creation of channels?

Comment: @Gary Russell - can you help in this issue please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are using a listener container; you must not `close()` its channel(s).

You need to `stop()` the container instead (which will close the channel).

Exactly how to do that depends on how you are using the framework - edit the question to show the configuration and your listener.

Comment: Thank you @Gary Russell for your reply . I m able to close the channel using simpleMessageListenerContainer .

Comment: How to get the container listener based on id from a spring scheduler